# Mapnik to reuse colors from geotiff when rendering png format

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, mapnik, png

I am trying to make mapnik read [this geotiff file](https://goo.gl/ncUcL6) and render it as a PNG file.

Unfortunately all the colors from the geotiff file are not retained. The resulting PNG is completely blank.

This is my Python code:

```
import mapnik

m = mapnik.Map(800, 600)
m.srs = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'

s = mapnik.Style()
r = mapnik.Rule()
s.rules.append(r)
m.append_style('Default', s)

ds = mapnik.Gdal(file='K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif', band=1)

layer = mapnik.Layer('layer')   
layer.datasource = ds
layer.styles.append('Default')
m.layers.append(layer)

m.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(m, 'mapnik.png', 'png32:z=1')
```

I can get some visible pixels and colors into the PNG by adding a RasterColorizer like this:

```
rs.colorizer = mapnik.RasterColorizer(mapnik.COLORIZER_DISCRETE, mapnik.Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
rs.colorizer.add_stop(-417, mapnik.Color(0, 0, 0))
rs.colorizer.add_stop(68, mapnik.Color(255, 255, 255))
rs.colorizer.add_stop(234, mapnik.Color(255, 0, 0))
rs.colorizer.add_stop(461, mapnik.Color(0, 0, 255))
rs.colorizer.add_stop(719, mapnik.Color(0, 255, 0))

s = mapnik.Style()
r = mapnik.Rule()
r.symbols.append(rs)
```

Which renders this PNG: [image: this image]

But then I need to manually define all the colours in the PNG, which just doesn't make sense when all the colours are already defined in the TIFF file. And in the example the PNG-colors are plain wrong and useless.

What am I missing to "reuse" the colors from the TIF in the rendered PNG ?

**SOLUTION**

Based on input from user30184 this Python code renders correctly:

```
import mapnik

map = mapnik.Map(800, 600)

style=mapnik.Style()
rule=mapnik.Rule()
rule.symbols.append(mapnik.RasterSymbolizer())
style.rules.append(rule)
map.append_style('Raster Style',style)
lyr = mapnik.Layer('GDAL Layer from TIFF file')
lyr.datasource = mapnik.Gdal(file='K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif')
lyr.styles.append('Raster Style')

map.srs = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'
map.layers.append(lyr)
map.zoom_all()

mapnik.render_to_file(map, 'mapnik.png', 'png32:z=1')
```

It renders this PNG:

[image]

Time to study the details...

Comment: Your tiff file has four bands, R, G, B and alpha. What is your aim when you read just the first band?

Comment: I am new to mapnik and the geotiff format; so my lack of knowledge my play a role. Do you mean that "band=1" should be "band=4" ?

Comment: Computers build colors from red, green, and blue components. Therefore you must read bands 1, 2, and 3. Fourth band (the alpha band) defines transparency. I am sure that you will find code examples from the net.

Comment: I do know that. I am also aware of other color models supported by TIFF. My question is how to bring these colours specified in the TIFF file to the rendered PNG file? I cannot find any examples via web search.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GDAL

Comment: Indeed. Now I can make it work. If you post as an answer I'll tick it off. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of the Mapnik GDAL PlugIn is documented in https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GDAL.

The original code selects only the first band of the source image

```
ds = mapnik.Gdal(file='K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif', band=1)
```

> **band**  **integer**     request for a specific raster band index, -1 means all
>   bands. Note that a band read from a single band raster gets
>   interpreted as Grayscale if band=-1 is specified while they retain
>   their original value when explicitly referenced with the "band"
>   parameter. This affects effectiveness of RasterColorizer

Band is an optional parameter and therefore you can read all bands either by using "band=-1" or shorter as in the example on the above mentioned wiki page:

```
lyr.datasource = mapnik.Gdal(file='K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif')
```

Usually it is not necessary to know how many bands the source file has but it is easy to check with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: K100_2017_1_20_612_62.tif
Size is 2000, 2000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","25832"]]
Origin = (620000.000000000000000,6140000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=6140_620
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Handmade Software, Inc. Image Alchemy v1.13
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=254
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=254
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  620000.000, 6140000.000) ( 10d53'40.34"E, 55d23'29.67"N)
Lower Left  (  620000.000, 6120000.000) ( 10d53' 9.58"E, 55d12'43.03"N)
Upper Right (  640000.000, 6140000.000) ( 11d12'36.18"E, 55d23'10.60"N)
Lower Right (  640000.000, 6120000.000) ( 11d12' 0.32"E, 55d12'24.09"N)
Center      (  630000.000, 6130000.000) ( 11d 2'51.61"E, 55d17'57.21"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```